# Granting access to all tables for a user

Tags: postgresql, best-practices, postgresql-9.1

I'm new to Postgres and trying to migrate our MySQL databases over.  In MySQL I can grant `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, and `DELETE` privileges on a low privileged user and enable those grants to apply to all tables in a specified database.  I must be missing something in Postgres because it looks like I have to grant those privileges for each table one at a time.  With many databases and hundreds of tables per database that seems like a daunting task just to get off the ground.  In addition, once a database is in operation, adding tables happens frequently enough that I wouldn't want to have to grant permissions each time unless absolutely necessary.

How is this best accomplished?

Answer (score 228, accepted):

First, you have to be able to connect to the database in order to run queries.  This can be achieved by

```
REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE your_database FROM PUBLIC;

GRANT CONNECT
ON DATABASE database_name 
TO user_name;
```

The `REVOKE` is necessary [because](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-grant.html)

> The key word PUBLIC indicates that the privileges are to be granted to
>   all roles, including those that might be created later. PUBLIC can be
>   thought of as an implicitly defined group that always includes all
>   roles. Any particular role will have the sum of privileges granted
>   directly to it, privileges granted to any role it is presently a
>   member of, and privileges granted to PUBLIC.

If you really want to restrict your user to DML statements, then you have a little more to do:

```
REVOKE ALL
ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public 
FROM PUBLIC;

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public 
TO user_name;
```

These assume that you will have only one schema (which is named 'public' by default).

As Jack Douglas pointed out, the above only gives the privileges for the **already existing** tables.  To achieve the same for future tables, you have to [define default privileges](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html):

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES 
    FOR ROLE some_role   -- Alternatively "FOR USER"
    IN SCHEMA public
    GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLES TO user_name;
```

Here, `some_role` is a role that creates the tables, while `user_name` is the one who gets the privileges.  Defining this, you have to be logged in as `some_role` or a member of it.

And, finally, you have to do the same for the sequences (thanks to PlaidFan for pointing it out) - here it is the `USAGE` privilege that you need.

Comment: Thanks, `FOR some_role` was the key part I was missing to make it work for my tables created later. But I didn't have to be logged in as `some_role`, it worked also if I executed the query as the default admin `postgres` user.

Comment: I did all those commands for my user, but still I wasn't allowed to use SELECT on the tables inside the database. It only worked after i REVOKED all privileges again and GRANTed again.

Comment: note updating (refreshing) materialized view requires extra permission if user is not the owner of the database. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/171932/postgresql-9-3-13-how-do-i-refresh-materialised-views-with-different-users

Comment: does REVOKE CONNECT FROM PUBLIC removes CONNECT priviledge from the superuser?

Comment: @MerajalMaksud it doesn't

Answer (score 66):

assuming you want to give them all privileges - do this:

```
grant all privileges on database dbname to dbuser;
```

where `dbname` is the name of your database and `dbuser` is the name of the user.

Comment: This will add the following privileges on the _database_: `CREATE, CONNECT, TEMPORARY`.  No privileges on tables.

Comment: A similar command for all tables would be, `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO dbuser;`

Comment: I found this useful too: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO dbuser;`

Comment: mysql bg? READ THE COMMENTS!

Answer (score 44):

Granting all privileges to all tables within the database is achieved with

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA <schema_name> TO <username>;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA <schema_name> TO <username>;
```

Comment: What if there are multiple schemas?

Comment: @asds_asds you'd have to execute it one by one for all the schemas you need.

Answer (score 24):

It may be that I was doing something wrong here since I am very new to PostgreSQL. But this only solved the first part of the problem for me - setting the privileges on all existing tables.

In order for permissions to be correctly set for my user on new tables, that are created I has to set default permissions for the user:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public
  GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON tables TO user_name;

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public
  GRANT SELECT, USAGE ON sequences TO user_name;
```

Answer (score 8):

```
--Create User

CREATE USER my_user_test WITH LOGIN NOSUPERUSER NOCREATEDB  NOCREATEROLE    INHERIT NOREPLICATION   CONNECTION LIMIT -1 PASSWORD 'xxxxxxx';

-- Grant connect to my data base

GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE my_db_test TO my_user_test;

-- Grant usage the schema

GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA my_sch_test TO my_user_test ;

-- Grant all table for SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA my_sch_test TO my_user_test;
```

Comment: What if I need to allow usage of multiple schemas, which have multiple tables