# PostgreSQL roles versus users, grant permissions

Tags: postgresql, users

I'm currently learning the differences between PostgreSQL and MySQL as I've got a new project and I also intend to migrate my existing software from MySQL to PostgreSQL. I've actually started creating an HTML table with a comparison of commands (for users/databases/command prompt, etc) between the two. After [reading an answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33943/granting-access-to-all-tables-for-a-user/33960#33960) here I've notice that `role` seems to be used as a group. With MySQL I have two users, basically public (`DELETE`, `INSERT`, `SELECT` and `UPDATE` permissions) and an admin user with a couple additional permissions.

So basically in the Windows 7 command prompt (local development only)...

- Is a role a user, group or a loosely used term specific to PostgreSQL?
- How do I grant only *specific* permissions to a specific user, for all tables in a database?
- How do I grant *all* permissions to a specific user, for all tables in a database?
- How, if at all, does a role compare to a user when using `GRANT` or `REVOKE` for user permissions?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

A *role* is an entity that can function as a user and/or as a group. A role `WITH LOGIN` can be used as a user, i.e. you can log in with it. Any role can function as a group, including roles that you can also log in as. So "user" and "group" are essentially terms that indicate the *intended usage* of a role, there's no real distinction between them.  Even in the PostgreSQL flavour of SQL the two are used more or less as synonyms.  For example, the documentation on [`CREATE USER`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createuser.html) says:

> CREATE USER is now an alias for CREATE ROLE.

Granting all ... [see the manual for `GRANT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html). You probably actually want to grant rights to `ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public` rather than *all tables* in the database.

Granting some rights ... same thing, but instead of `GRANT ALL` use `GRANT SELECT, INSERT` for example. Again, see the manual.

A role *is* a user, and/or a group. You can only grant to roles, because roles are all that there is.

Comment: Great explanation!

Comment: So ... what is the syntax for granting all rights to all tables in schema public?

Comment: @AlxVallejo [this should help](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=postgres+granting+all+rights+to+all+tables+in+schema). Try the top link, or read the `GRANT` documentation page where it lists `ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA`