# Can't alter default privileges

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I followed the steps below.

1. I installed PostgreSQL.
2. I logged in as `postgres` via (`sudo -i -u postgres`)
3. I created new user `new_user` via shell script `createuser --interactive`
4. I granted that user permission to create databases.
5. I created database: `createdb new_db`.

Now I want to give `new_user` privileges be able to perform all default DML operations on tables created by himself (command bellow taken from this [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33943/)), so I typed:

```
postgres=# ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR new_user IN SCHEMA 
    public GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLES TO new_user;
```

But got an error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "new_user"
LINE 1: ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR new_user IN SCHEMA public GRANT...
```

I have no idea why this command is not working.

Comment: What version of Postgres?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter 9.3.9

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A key word is missing. It must be:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE new_user IN SCHEMA public GRANT...
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html)

> ```
> ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES
>     [ FOR { ROLE | USER } target_role [, ...] ]
> ```

One of both (`{ ROLE | USER }`) is required.

Note that the particular command does not make any sense to begin with because, ([quoting the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html#SQL-GRANT-DESCRIPTION-OBJECTS)):

> There is no need to grant privileges to the owner of an object
> (usually the user that created it), as the owner has all privileges by default.

If you want that to grant permissions for objects that a different user (like `postgres`) created then use:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE postgres
GRANT ALL ON TABLES TO new_user;
```

You probably wouldn't want to restrict that to a particular schema.

And you typically want to grant privileges on sequences, too:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE postgres
GRANT ALL ON SEQUENCES TO new_user;
```

Comment: Why do people not use tab completion =(