# Alter default privileges for role

Tags: postgresql, permissions, postgresql-9.5

I have database called Blackacre and two roles who have access to it: *johnrole* and *janerole*. *janerole* has been granted `ALL` privileges and *johnrole* has only been granted the `SELECT` privilege.

Problem is when a user from *janerole* creates a new table, then a user from *johnrole* can't `SELECT` from the new table.

> ```
> ERROR:  permission denied for relation mopery
> ```

I tried to use `ALTER DEFAULT` in different ways to automate that:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE johnrole IN SCHEMA public
   GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO johnrole;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO johnrole;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE johnrole GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO PUBLIC;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO GROUP johnrole;
```

None of them work and I still end up with the same error.

When I use `ALTER DEFAULT` to automate future tables privileges for user e.g *john* then everything works, he can `SELECT` from new tables created in the database without any error.

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO john;
```

This is how I added people to roles:

```
GRANT johnrole TO adam;
GRANT janerole TO eva;
```

Granted usage on Blackacre database like this:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO johnrole;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO janerole;
```

Gave some privileges like that:

```
GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO janerole;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO johnrole;
```

After that I tried to give automatic privileges with `ALTER DEFAULT` as above described don't work. Any ideas how to get default privileges working properly?

Answer (score 12):

> `janerole` has been granted `ALL` privileges and `johnrole` has only been granted the `SELECT` privilege.

You got at least one aspect of the command backwards in all your attempts:
Alter default privileges for the role that creates objects - which in turn grants privileges to another role. I.e.:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE janerole IN SCHEMA public
GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO johnrole;
```

Do this while logged in as `janerole` (or a member of the role or a superuser).

Note that default privileges *only* apply to the target role, not to members of this role.

And don't forget to `GRANT USAGE ON SEQUENCES` as well if you have any `serial` columns. Possibly `SELECT` and `UPDATE`, too.

There may be more problems, the question is not completely clear.

Related:

- [How to manage DEFAULT PRIVILEGES for USERs on a DATABASE vs SCHEMA?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117109/how-to-manage-default-privileges-for-users-on-a-database-vs-schema/117661#117661)
- [Can't alter default privileges](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114834/cant-alter-default-privileges/114839#114839)

Comment: When default privileges only apply to the target role then how I'm going to automate these privileges to members of this role aswell? Because giving rights only to role where this role users don't get these rights is kinda pointless.

Comment: @Gen: Typically, you would have a *single* role to create objects. Members of the role can issue a [`SET ROLE janerole`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-set-role.html) before creating tables. Also, default privileges are *not* rights (or privileges), it's a convenience feature. Whoever grants the role  `janerole` to another role can also set default privileges if applicable.

Comment: "Note that default privileges only apply to the target role, not to members of this role." Is this true even if the role has INHERIT flag?

Comment: @Gajus I think the point is that when you alter default privileges, you are only altering default privileges of objects created by the _role_ / `user` that is executing the command. New tables created by `janerole` would be accessible by `johnrole`, but a new table created by `postgresAdmin` would not (assuming we're in a custom schema so we don't have to deal with the public schema intricacies)