# How do I GRANT for all tables across all schemas

Tags: postgresql-9.2, permissions

I want to

```
GRANT SELECT
    ON ALL TABLES
    TO foo;
```

But postgres tells me I have a syntax error at "TO". It expects a GRANT like:

```
GRANT SELECT
    ON ALL TABLES
    IN SCHEMA public
    TO foo;
```

We have a handful of tables that have been sharded such that `public`, `shard123`, and `shard124` all have a table `my_table`, and `public.my_table` is the parent of both `shard123.my_table` and `shard124.my_table`. I've GRANTed SELECT to foo for public schema, but foo doesn't have permission for any of the shard schemas.

I've also done:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES
    FOR ROLE dba
    GRANT SELECT
    ON TABLES
    TO foo;
```

...which should automatically grant for any new tables and schemas made from now on.

There are 1000 < n < 10000 shards/schemas, so GRANTing separately for each shard/schema is impractical.

How can I GRANT to a role for all existing tables across all existing schemas (all shards)?

Or even better, can I GRANT for all schemas `LIKE 'shard%'`?

Answer (score 4):

If you need to do this only once, the quickest way is probably the following.

Find all the schemas you want to touch by querying, for example, the `pg_namespace` system catalog:

```
SELECT nspname 
FROM pg_namespace
WHERE nspname LIKE 'shard%'; -- tweak this to your needs
```

Then we can expand the query output into `GRANT` statements:

```
SELECT 'GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA ' || nspname || ' TO foo;'
FROM pg_namespace
WHERE nspname LIKE 'shard%';
```

This will give you an enormous amount of statements, which you can just copy over and run.  As you have a big number of schemas, the easiest is possibly the following (running it in `psql`):

```
\copy (SELECT 'GRANT ...' ...) TO some_local_file.sql

\i some_local_file.sql
```

Of course, if you prefer, you could do this using dynamic SQL, too - I find the above solution slightly better, as it leaves a file behind with the actions taken, that can then be checked in under version control.

If you happen to use a `psql` version 9.6 (or later), there is just another possibility using [`\gexec`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS):

```
SELECT 'GRANT SELECT ...'
... -- you can even omit the semicolon here 
\gexec
```

**Notes:**

- I've written an answer about a similar issue a while ago - you may find useful details [there](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/33960/6219).
- there is no possibility of doing this from `GRANT`, unfortunately.  As it is not uncommon what you need here, I'd expect this functionality appearing sooner or later.
- just to emphasize, the above commands will do the trick for the already existing tables.  Future tables need the default privileges (which you've set, for a given role).