# Grant READ ONLY permissions to all tables in all databases

Tags: postgresql, permissions, postgresql-12

I created new role named "support" in my PostgreSQL. Now I need grant "READ ONLY" permissions for this role an ALL exists databases/tables. 
Also I need automatically granted same permissions on each DB that will created in future.

I unsuccessfully tried next queries for grant permissions in new databases (Can not select from new database tables ):

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE support GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO PUBLIC;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES to support;
```

I looked at [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121522/how-do-i-grant-for-all-tables-across-all-schemas), but it about all tables within single database. It not enough for me.

Comment: I looked this post. It's about all tables in one database. I need all tables in all databases on my server.

Comment: When you know how to catch a fish, it's reasonable to expect that you can catch other fishes of that kind using the same technique.

Comment: @mustaccio, I have few hundreds databases on my server, so i search simple solution without iterate queries on each of them. All help will be appreciate.

Comment: There is no other solution.