# Role, whose name doesn't match database name, can't access the database

Tags: postgresql, permissions, postgresql-9.3

Role `app` can access database `app`. But role `app2` can't. I don't see any specific privileges for role `app`, and it's not an owner according to `\l`:

```
app2=> \l

      Name       |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |    Access privileges
-----------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------
 app             | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres            +
                 |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres   +
                 |          |          |             |             | app=CTc/postgres        +
                 |          |          |             |             | app2=CTc/postgres
...

app2=> \dp
                                               Access privileges
 Schema |                    Name                     |   Type   | Access privileges | Column access privileges
--------+---------------------------------------------+----------+-------------------+--------------------------
 public | access_users                                | table    |                   |
 public | access_users_id_seq                         | sequence |                   |
...


app2=> select * from users;
ERROR:  permission denied for relation users
```

Why role `app` is able to access database? What can I check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it sounds, the *tables* (not necessary the database) is owned by the `app` user.  This is what the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html) tells about this:

> If the "Access privileges" column is empty for a given object, it means the object has default privileges (that is, its privileges column is null). Default privileges always include all privileges for the owner, and can include some privileges for PUBLIC depending on the object type, as explained above.

As nothing is displayed under "Access privileges" in the `\dp` output, and the `app` user can read from and write to the table, it is clear that it's the owner.  One can prove this, for example, by issuing `\dt access_users`, which should return something like

```
        List of relations
 Schema │ Name         │ Type  │ Owner  
────────┼──────────────┼───────┼───────
 public │ access_users │ table │ app
```

This also means (not surprisingly), that no other user (except superusers and the members of the `app` role) has access to the tables.  If you want `app2` to have some rights on them (and future tables), an [earlier answer of mine](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/33960/6219) might be interesting.