# Create, Drop permissions

Tags: postgresql

I would like to grant create, select, update, drop permissions only for user USER_NAME for a particular schema SCHEMA_NAME. It is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
GRANT select, update on all tables in schema SCHEMANAME to ROLE;
GRANT select, update on all sequences in schema SCHEMANAME to ROLE;
GRANT create on schema SCHEMANAME to ROLE;
```

You cannot provide grants to drop an object to any other user besides its owner. Only the superuser or owner has the permission to drop the object.

Comment: I think `USAGE` has to be also granted on the schema.  Furthermore, this applies to all existing tables, but to none that will be created in the future.  To this end, default privileges has to be set, too.  See https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/33960/6219, for example.