# Enforce conditions on queries

Tags: postgresql, role, policy-based-management

Currently I have a simple schema, a `sites` table and an `items` table.

`Sites` own many `items`, `items` has a `siteId` column to store the reference of the site which owns it.

I'd like to be able to enforce a condition when querying `items`, meaning returning an error if it is not queried with a `siteId` - in practice:

- `select * from items` would fail
- `select * from items where siteId = 1` would succeed, albeit a site record with id 1 exists

This can easily be achieved on an application level.

I recently started investigating further into row level policies, roles, functions, etc… which I found very interesting as they enable lower level setups. That is, I'm still new about it and lack understanding/knowledge. I was wondering if the use case described above could simply be solved within SQL (via a combination of policies, functions, etc… or any other Postgres builtin tools)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility (one that you feel intuitively, apparently) is to centralize your query into a function and disable querying otherwise.

Let's say the tables are owned by a role called `owner`, and there is a `reader` to run `SELECT` queries against the tables.  Then there is an `application` role which can connect to the DB and is able to call functions.  All this can be achieved by:

```
-- log in as a superuser, for example
CREATE ROLE owner;
CREATE ROLE reader;
CREATE USER application WITH PASSWORD 'a';

SET ROLE TO owner;

CREATE SCHEMA data;

CREATE TABLE data.important (i_id serial PRIMARY KEY);  -- will be owned by owner

GRANT SELECT ON data.important TO reader;
```

At this point, whoever can assume the `reader` role (by being a member and/or using `SET ROLE`) will be able to run any `SELECT` against the table.  Note that `application` doesn't have any rights here.

Then create another schema for your functions:

```
CREATE SCHEMA api; -- well, you can call it something else, too

RESET ROLE; -- to switch back to your superuser self

CREATE FUNCTION api.select_important(id integer) 
RETURNS data.important
LANGUAGE sql
SECURITY DEFINER -- the important bit
AS $$
SELECT * FROM data.important WHERE i_id = id;
$$;

GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA api TO application;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION api.select_important(integer) TO application;
```

The `SECURITY DEFINER` clause will make the function inherit the rights of the superuser to read from the table (there is no need to grant it).  Now if you log in as `application`, you can call the function:

```
\c - application 
Password for user application: 

SELECT * FROM api.select_important(1);
 i_id 
──────

(1 row)
```

However, you cannot read from the table directly:

```
my=> SELECT * FROM data.important WHERE i_id = 1;
ERROR:  permission denied for schema data
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM data.important WHERE i_id = 1;
```

**Note:** to spare `GRANT`s all the time you create a table or function, you can set default privileges.  See the bottom part of an [earlier answer of mine](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/33960/6219) about how to do that.

Comment: thx a lot for this enlightment! i was not even aware of such schema use; it makes sense now. Besides that, as you sounds way more experienced than me; is such pattern common, if not , acceptable ? Or most seasoned dba would still leave such setups to the app layer ?