# What is the equivalent of SQL Server's db_datareader/db_datawriter in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, role

I'm porting an application from SQL Server to PostgreSQL. Most of this is simple as the application only really does simple selects, inserts and updates. However I need to create a user to access the database. The SQL Sever code creates its user like this:

```
USE [master] CREATE LOGIN [ExampleUserName] WITH PASSWORD = 'ExamplePassword', CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=ON;
USE [ExampleDB];
CREATE USER [ExampleUserName] FOR LOGIN [ExampleUserName];
ALTER ROLE [db_datawriter] ADD MEMBER [ExampleUserName];
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [ExampleUserName];
```

What is the equivalent of that in PostgreSQL?

Comment: i don't think postgres has anything exactly like that... usually you grant permissions on the resource to `public` and then anyone with login access to the database can use them...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no builtin role like that in PostgreSQL.  However, you can set up one:

```
CREATE ROLE db_datawriter;
```

After this, you have to assign write privileges (usually `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, maybe `TRUNCATE`) to it.  To see how to do this for all present and future tables, read my older [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/33960/6219).

Normally, write access also implicates reads, therefore it make sense to add `db_datawriter` as a member of `db_datareader` (which was set up similarly, but with `SELECT` only):

```
GRANT db_datareader TO db_datawriter;
```

Then you can grant these two to different login users (or other roles) as necessary:

```
CREATE USER example_user IN ROLE db_datareader;
```

Note that [`CREATE USER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createuser.html) implicates being able to log in, unlike `CREATE ROLE`.