# postgresql grant user privilages to dynamically created tables

Tags: postgresql, permissions, crud

We have 2 postgresql users. One user (`dbworkeruser`) for creating tables dynamically (from C# worker) and other user (`injestworkeruser`) for inserting data into these tables (from another C# worker as well).
The main issue that we have is that, every time we do drop/create new tables dynamically (on runtime) we get exception that the user `injestworkeruser` doesn't have enough permission to select or insert data from/into these newly created tables. This is the created user:

```
CREATE USER injestworkeruser WITH
  LOGIN
  NOSUPERUSER
  INHERIT
  NOCREATEDB
  NOCREATEROLE
  NOREPLICATION;
```

Is there anyway to grant the user permissions to apply CRUD operations to any newely created table?

This one didn't work for me as this applies to the existing tables:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO injestworkeruser;
```

Comment: [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/221209/grant-all-on-all-tables-in-schema-does-not-allow-user-to-see-tables/221212#221212) may help

Answer (score 1):

Set your default privileges for the schema using [`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html)

Answer (score -1):

GRANT usage ON SCHEMA createuser TO consume;

alter default privileges for user createuser in schema createuser grant select on tables  to consume;

This will work perfect.