# Can't create read-write Postgresql user

Tags: postgresql, permissions, schema, users

I'm trying to create two users in a Postgres database—one with read-write access to all tables in two schemas, and one with read-write-create (i.e., able to make DDL changes) to the same schemas.

I currently have these statements.

```
CREATE SCHEMA
    schema_a;

CREATE SCHEMA
    schema_b;

CREATE ROLE read;
CREATE ROLE read_write;
CREATE ROLE read_write_create;

GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA schema_a, schema_b TO read;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schema_a, schema_b TO read;

GRANT INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schema_a, schema_b TO read_write;
GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA schema_a, schema_b TO read_write;

GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA schema_a, schema_b TO read_write_create;

GRANT read to read_write;
GRANT read_write to read_write_create;

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA schema_a, schema_b GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO read;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA schema_a, schema_b GRANT SELECT ON SEQUENCES TO read;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA schema_a, schema_b GRANT INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLES TO read_write;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA schema_a, schema_b GRANT SELECT, UPDATE ON SEQUENCES TO read_write;

CREATE USER
    read_write_user
WITH PASSWORD
    'a_password';

GRANT read_write TO read_write_user;

CREATE USER
    read_write_create_user
WITH PASSWORD
    'another_password';

GRANT read_write_create TO read_write_create_user;
```

After running these, `read_write_create_user` can create tables, read from, and write to all tables. But `read_write_user` can't read or write to any tables created by `read_write_create_user`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the tables in either schema are created by a different role (I assume `read_write_create_user`) than the one the default privileges were defined for (which is you, or the role that run the above set of statements).

You'll find a bit more explanation in [my older answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/33960/6219).

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a little confused. I updated my statements to read `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE read_write_create IN SCHEMA schema_a, schema_b...`, but I still have the same issue. Is there something else I need to change?

Comment: It has to be executed for "read_write_create_user" if that is who is creating the tables.  It is not an inherited property. Which means it has to be executed after that role is created.

Comment: @jjanes Are you saying I should have `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER read_write_create_user IN SCHEMA schema_a, schema_b...`?

Comment: @jjanes I also tried updating to `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER read_write_create_user IN SCHEMA schema_a, schema_b...TO read_write_user, read_write_create_user` but that didn't work either.

Comment: @KrisHarper  works for me.  Did you look at tables created **after** you did the new `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES..`?

Comment: Although probably better would be to stick with your original defaults, and have read_write_create_user do a `set role read_write_create;` before creating things.

Comment: @jjanes Okay, I think I got it. I didn't realize that the `ALTER DEFAULT` statements had to be executed by `read_write_create_user`. Do you have any links to some best practices on this? I am new to Postgres and to be honest I find it very confusing that permissions for tables depend on which user created the table (and which user created the permission, even).