# Create a read-write user and a read-only user

Tags: postgresql, permissions, amazon-rds

I'm trying to do what I think is a common setup for a PostgreSQL database on a RDS instance. I want to have:

- Either on `public` schema, or on a custom schema I don't especially care
- A read-write user
- A read-only user
- The read-write user should be able to create a table in the schema
- The read-only user should be able to read from this new table automatically, i.e. without an additional `GRANT`

I tried to follow this [AWS blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/managing-postgresql-users-and-roles/) and [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33943/granting-access-to-all-tables-for-a-user/33960#33960) but it seems I'm hitting a wall.

I've tried the following to no avail, `postgres` user is the user created by RDS that has the role `rds_superuser`:

```sql
-- Making sure roles can't do anything on the database without explicit grant
REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE my_database FROM PUBLIC;
CREATE SCHEMA my_schema;

-- Read-write
CREATE ROLE read_write;

GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE my_database TO read_write;
GRANT USAGE, CREATE ON SCHEMA my_schema TO read_write;

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA my_schema TO read_write;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA my_schema GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLES TO read_write;

GRANT USAGE ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA my_schema TO read_write;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA my_schema GRANT USAGE ON SEQUENCES TO read_write;

-- Read-only
CREATE ROLE read_only;

GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE my_database TO read_only;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA my_schema TO read_only;

GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA my_schema TO read_only;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA my_schema GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO read_only;

-- Users
CREATE USER read_write_user WITH PASSWORD 'password_1';
GRANT read_write TO my_database;

CREATE USER read_only_user WITH PASSWORD 'password_2';
GRANT read_only TO my_database_read_only;
```

When I connect to the database with user `read_write_user`, I can create a new table `my_table`, but if I connect with user `read_only_user`, I can't access it, I get the following error: `permission denied for table my_table`.

I connected back with the user `postgres` and saw that I didn't have rights to grant access to this table to `read_only` role:

```sql
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA my_schema TO read_only;
```

leads to this error: `no privileges were granted for "my_table"`.

So if I understand correctly `postgres` user doesn't have enough rights to grant access to objects created by `read_write_user` and the `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` didn't do what I thought it would do.

I tried to add the following queries on a new database before revoking/granting anything:

```sql
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE my_database TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA my_schema TO postgres;
```

and it didn't help.

I have the feeling that this is linked to the fact the `rds_superuser` is not a real `superuser` but I don't know how to go forward, is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` only affects tables created by the user who ran the `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` statement.

You'd have to do this:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE read_write IN SCHEMA my_schema
   GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO read_only;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm trying to use this but it doesn't seem to work either. I tried this query with my `rds_superuser` (I needed to add an additional `GRANT read_write TO postgres` because the user doesn't have the rights) and with the `read_write_user` directly but I still get `permission denied for table my_table` for `read_only_user`, I recreated the table after the `ALTER` query to be sure.

Comment: You have to create the table as `read_write` after you ran the `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` in the same database, then it will work.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, I wanted to say that I did that already and it didn't work.

Comment: Then you did something wrong, like run the statements in different databases. Examine the settings with `\ddp` in `psql`. Try to come up with a short SQL script to reproduce your problem and add it to the question.

Comment: Nice answer, very succinct

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I unfortunately don't find the time to retest thoroughly your solution, it seems it should work so I'll accept your answer and update when I can. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Default permissions seem to apply only from the creator but not from inherited roles. I.e. if you want for default permissions from read_write user to be applied to a new table, the table must be created by read_write itself and not by another user which belongs to read_write role.

Comment: @StanislavGerman-Evtushenko Yes, that is correct.